# Regular Expression for finding HTML tags leaves empty tags behind in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, forms

I'm trying to remove all hidden tags (and the ending  tag) via regular expression and it seems to work but with one problem. It leaves behind "<>" for all the elements found.

I'm using this to replace my hidden fields with blank:

```
$saveContent = preg_replace('<input type="hidden" .*? />', "", $saveContent);
$saveContent = preg_replace('</form>', "", $saveContent);
```

It just brings back "<><><>" (2 Hidden fields and the ending form tag). I tried to string replace <> and that doesn't seem to work either

Am I missing something?

Comment: Whenever you try to parse HTML with regex, you make a kitten cry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out for some reason (that I wasn't aware of), the < and > symbols were being converted to entities, but only for a select few.

I just checked for those entities and string replaced them to the correct symbols and it worked.

Comment: The regexes in your question are still incorrect, as @Qtax explained.  Did you also add regex delimiters, as in `'~</form>~'` ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem (except that of trying to match HTML with regex) is that you don't properly quote the expression inside the string, which is usually done in PHP like `"/regex/"`, but any character can be used instead of the slashes, eg `"~regex~"`.

In your case `<` is the quoting character, which makes the end quote `>` (i.e `"<regex>"`), thus making it valid in `preg_*` and not giving you any errors.

For example:

```
preg_replace('</form>', "", $str)
```

is the same as

```
preg_replace('~/form~', "", $str)
```

and

```
preg_replace('/\/form/', "", $str)
```

All of which replace `/form` with an empty string.

While you wanted:

```
preg_replace('~</form>~', "", $str)
```

Comment: Say rather that `<` and `>` are the *regex delimiters*.  "Quoting character" could just as easily refer to the quotes (`"` or `'`) surrounding the whole regex, or to the escape character, ```\```.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape slashes.. and add slashes for modifiers to work http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

```
$saveContent = preg_replace('/<input type="hidden" .*? \/>/i', "", $saveContent);    
$saveContent = preg_replace('/<\/form>/i', "", $saveContent);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything. It leaves the form tag there.

Comment: Try replacing `>/i` with simply `>/`.

Comment: How is making it case-sensitive help?

Comment: Wops I though reversed. Forgot that `/i` was the case insensitive version, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you can put the pattern between %'s as to avoid all that escaping which makes practical unreadable, for example

```
if (preg_match('%</form>%', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: No dice, it doesn't find </form> even though it's there.

Comment: that's just weird :) If its literally there I'm thinking that it's an encoding issue of some sort? Try simpler forms like a match and just "form" then add <, then > and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$content = '<input type="hidden" name="abc" /> abc <input type="hidden" name="abc" />';
preg_replace('#<input type="hidden"[^>]+>#', '', $content);
```